# DFS Migration while keeping the same Name

Tags: dfs, windows-server-2022

I was able to lab out the following steps and achieved desired results but I was wondering if there was a better or "cleaner" way to what I would like to do?

Desired Goal: To keep the same server name on the new server, so that the path stays the same in DFS Namespace Servers list.

Scenario: I need to decommission Server A (old) and rename Server B (new) as "Server A" when all is said and done so that the transition is seamless.

Steps to execute:

1. Install DFS Management on Server B (new)
2. Add Server B to Namespace Servers
3. Create Replication Group for both servers.
4. Let it marinate and transfer all the data so that both servers are in synch.
5. Disable network connectivity on the Original Server (Server A).
6. Rename Server B (new) to "Server A".
7. Adjust DNS entries to point to the correct IP address.
8. Delete Server with name "Server B" as a Namespace Server.
9. Delete Anything pointing to name "Server B"  in Replication.
10. Delete Replication Group.
11. Delete folder targets with path to server name "Server B".

I must absolutely keep the same server name.

Anything wrong with this approach?

Thank you all for taking the time to read this!